# masm assembly change the color of any thing on screen by using code

Tags: windows, assembly, colors, masm

I am making a color picker and I want to display the color they have selected. I cant figure out how to change the color of anything. I have tried yo change textbox color or the background color of the windows form.

So my question is if anyone can show me how to change the color of anything on the screen(I would prefer background of the windows form)

my color picker shows them the color in the form of hexadecimal like FFFFFF or 00FFFFFFh

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hows about this: 
[MASM - ChooseColor Dialog](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/262070-masm-choosecolor-dialog/)